# Code for computing the centroid of a polygon's kernel

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal

I am interested in computing the centroid of the kernel of a planar polygon.
The kernel of any polygon is convex and I know that the kernel itself can be computed in linear time. From there, the centroid (simple average should probably be good enough for me) can be easily computed in linear time as well.
However, I do not want to go through the hassle of implementing it myself.
I do not care too much about efficiency as my polygons are small (have 6 vertices on average). Even O(n^2) code can work.

A reliable simple to use c++ code that can be used as is will be optimal.
My code is linked with CGAL, so if CGAL can compute this, it would be great.

Comment: By "kernel", do you mean convex hull?

Comment: No. The kernel is a region such that any point inside it “sees” the entire polygon.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one function in CGAL that computes the kernel of a 2D polygon, if that's what you were looking for.